# Comparar multiplos resultados em foreach

Tags: php

Preciso comparar entre duas tabelas os valores salvos no banco e trazer em um option os resultados (tb_carteiras e tb_carteirasclientes), caso mais de um registro deve ser inserido o selected.

Na tabela tb_carteiras eu tenho 10 registros com id e nome
Na tabela tb_carteirasclientes eu tenho 2 registros com id e carteira

Eu preciso que no select ele dê o selected="selected" quando os id.tb_carteiras e carteira.tb_carteirasclientes forem iguais

No script abaixo só acontece no primeiro registro de comparação e não passa para o segundo.

```
    <select class="selectpicker" data-style="select-with-transition" multiple title="Selecione a Carteira:<code>*</code>" required="true" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" title="Carteira" name="carteira[]" id="carteira">
<?php
$readSes = new Read;
$readSes->FullRead("
SELECT
tb_carteiras.nome,
tb_carteiras.id,
tb_carteirasclientes.carteira
FROM `tb_carteiras` 
LEFT JOIN `tb_carteirasclientes` 
ON `tb_carteirasclientes`.carteira = `tb_carteiras`.id
ORDER BY
tb_carteiras.id ASC
");
if (!$readSes->getResult()):
    echo '<option disabled="disabled" value="null"> Nenhuma Carteira cadastrado. </option>';
else:
    foreach ($readSes->getResult() as $ses):
        echo "<option value=\"{$ses['id']}\" ";
        if ($ses['id'] == $ClienteData['carteira']):
            echo ' selected="selected" ';
        endif;
        echo "> {$ses['nome']} </option>";
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Certo... perdão pela inocência, mas o que etá acontecendo? Não está funcionando ou está trazendo alguma coisa errada como resultado? Passando pelo código não vi algo que possa estar errado no meu ponto de vista...

Comment: Como o @RodrigoTognin disse, tente ser mais completo... o SQL está retornando os valores certos? Se não, qual a estrutura do banco? Se sim, qual é o HTML resultante? E o resultado que deveria ter?

Comment: Talvez não expliquei direito, nessa tabela auxiliar eu posso ter 2 registros que constam na tabela principal, e eu preciso que esses dados estejam checados e está vindo apenas 1

Comment: Você faz o select principal, lê no `foreach`, enquanto faz outra consulta e compara os resultados. Não seria isso?

Comment: Atualmente só faço esse foreach, queria saber como comparar ambos para que no select fique mais de um campo selected

Answer (score 0):

Consegui achar o erro, não sei se é a melhor prática porém funcionou, usei a variável comparativa $ses['carteira'] para comparar o $ses['id'] dentro do foreach, e veio certo. (abaixo)

```
foreach ($readSes->getResult() as $ses):
 echo "<option value=\"{$ses['id']}\" ";
 if ($ses['id'] == $ses['carteira']):
  echo ' selected="selected" ';
 endif;
 echo "> {$ses['nome']} </option>";
endforeach;
```

Obrigado aos que ajudaram.